# Macbook Pro Mid-2012 Retina Screen Flicker

Tags: mac, display, screen

Basically as it says in the title, whenever I use my computer the screen flickers and it's unusable. This isn't just when I log into one account, this is on startup, login, while using the computer, and in the windows partition. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6TTt9SXnso). I have tried a PRAM reset and a normal reboot but both are not working.

Comment: what size screen is it?

Answer (score 2):

Certain MacBook Pros made between February 2011 and December 2013 were found by Apple to be defective.  Apple is offering to repair them for free.  The symptoms were:

> - Distorted or scrambled video on the computer screen
> - No video on the computer screen (or external display) even though the computer is on
> - Computer restarts unexpectedly

**Affected Models**:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch Early 2011)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch Early 2011)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch Late 2011)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inch, Early 2013)

You have two repair options:

**Carry In**

- Bring your MacBook Pro to a participating provider - Apple Retail Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider.
- A technician will run a diagnostic test on the MacBook Pro to verify eligibility.
- Repair turn around time will vary based upon parts and technician availability.
- You will be notified when your MacBook Pro is ready for pickup.

**Mail In**

- Call Apple and request a postage paid box to send your MacBook Pro to the local Apple Repair Center.
- A technician will run a diagnostic test on your MacBook Pro to verify eligibility.
- The repair process takes approximately 5-7 days from the time your MacBook Pro is received at the repair center until it is returned to you.
- After it has been serviced, your MacBook Pro will be returned to you by mail.

See [Apple's page on this topic](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware issue. It's likely that the screen or logic board will need to be replaced.

Personally, I would take the laptop apart and trace down the screen's cable and make sure it is not pinched. Also, disconnect & reconnect. I've seen some instances where this was the culprit. Unfortunately more often, it's the screen or logic board.

Here are a couple a how-to that shows how to take the MBP apart, should be helpful to ensure wire isn't pinched, and worse case, replace screen or logic board:

- [How-to Replace MacBook Pro Screen](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2012+Display+Assembly+Replacement/9708)
- [How-to Replace MacBook Pro Logic Board](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Logic+Board+Replacement/10766)

Comment: Thanks, anything else you might suggest? Warranty just expired.